# node.js on Windows - npm install just hangs

Tags: node.js

Installed node.js ver 0.10.13, 64 bit on windows 7. I tried  npm install commander, npm install cheerio, npm install mysql.  None of the npm installs work. It hangs with message, Example: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander.
Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Does it get completed/ show error. How long does it hang.

Comment: https://registry.npmjs.org/commander appears to be using a self-signed SSL cert, which is why your browser gives a scary warning if you go there. Probably the npm installer is giving up because of that. Try using http instead if possible.